# Put Javascript Promise into Functions

Tags: javascript, function, promise

I have two promises that I am resolving with promise.all:

```
var mictest1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(true);
});
var mictest2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(true);
});

Promise.all([mictest1, mictest2]).then(data => {
  console.log("test passed: " + data);
})
```

I would like to put the promises `mictest1` and `mictest2` into a function called `mictest()` so it does the following:

```
mictest();

Promise.all([mictest1, mictest2]).then(data => {
  console.log("test passed: " + data);
})
```

In this way I can call the function at will, and when the promises get complicated, i don't have that block of text in front of `promise.all`

Comment: so, you want `mictest` to populate two global variables, mictest1 and mictest2, with promises? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for the `mictest` function to return the `Promise.all`?

```js
const mictest = () => {
  var mictest1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true);
  });
  var mictest2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true);
  });
  return Promise.all([mictest1, mictest2]);
};


mictest().then((data) => {
  console.log('test passed:', data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a function that *returns* the promise:

```
function mictest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true);
  });
}
```

You'd use it like

```
var mictest1 = mictest();
var mictest2 = mictest();
Promise.all([mictest1, mictest2]).then(data => {
  console.log("test passed: " + data);
})
```

or simply

```
Promise.all([mictest(), mictest()]).then(data => {
  console.log("test passed: " + data);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the way you imagined it but you can get very close:

```
let promises = mictest();

Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
  console.log("test passed: " + data);
})
```

That's just changing two lines of your imagined code. The implementation is simple:

```
function mictest () {
  return [
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(true);
    }),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(true);
    })
  ]
}
```

A promise is a value just like strings, numbers, arrays etc. You can treat it like any value. It just happens to be an object that has a `.then()` method and is awaitable

> Note: actually, any object with a `.then()` method is awaitable even your own custom created non-promise object (actually any object with a `.then()` method is a promise even though it is not a Promise)